# XML document doesn't return value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XML document and console application written in C# and I need to read some data from XML. For this I try as shown below but instead of `Aram` I get nothing.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("rate", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
doc.Load(@"task.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList myNodes = root.SelectNodes("Users/User/Name", nsmgr);
if (myNodes != null)
{
    foreach (var item in myNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

Here is also the XML document.

```
<Users xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:User>
        <xsl:Name>Aram</xsl:Name>
        <xsl:Lastname>Vardanyan</xsl:Lastname>
        <xsl:Email>aram.vardanyan.y@gmail.com</xsl:Email>
        <xsl:Phone>077 195973</xsl:Phone>
   </xsl:User>
</Users>
```

Comment: You have a typo `Useres`. Also check out the newer XDocument rather than XmlDocument

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I corrected that but nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three issues in the code :

1 - You don't have `rate` namespace change it to `xsl`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");
```

2 - Prefix `User` and `Name` by `xsl` for `SelectNodes`:

```
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList myNodes = root.SelectNodes("/Users/xsl:User/xsl:Name", nsmgr);
```

3 - `item` is `XmlNode` type, then `Console.WriteLine(item)` will not display the expected result, change `var` to `XmlNode` and display the `InnerText` :

```
foreach (XmlNode item in myNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

The whole code :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

doc.Load(@"task.xml");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList myNodes = root.SelectNodes("/Users/xsl:User/xsl:Name", nsmgr);
if (myNodes != null)
{
    foreach (XmlNode item in myNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
}
```

**Result**

```
Aram
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

U can also LINQ to XML class to achieve the same in functional way. Check out the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) to more insight of rich apis to query, modify and many more.

```
        //load the element users
        XElement element = XElement.Load("task.xml");

        //Get the namespace with prefix "xsl"
        XNamespace @namespace = element.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsl");

        //Get all childrens of Users element
        IEnumerable<XElement> users = element.Elements(XName.Get("User", @namespace.NamespaceName));

        foreach (XElement user in users)
        {
            XElement username = user.Element(XName.Get("Name", @namespace.NamespaceName));
            Console.WriteLine(username.Value);
        }
```